# Nodejs Object Document Model for Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, mongoose, odm, ohm

I'm want use an ODM for redis in node.js.  Does anybody have any experience using any?  I ideally want something that is somewhat the equivalent of [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose) (except instead for Redis instead of Mongodb).

The two I have heard of so far are [nohm](https://github.com/maritz/nohm) and [ron](http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-ron/).  Can someone compare the experience of using either of these?  Also I have read about [redback](https://github.com/chriso/redback) and I am curious if it would work well with an ODM.

Comment: Just to be nit-picky - Redis is not a *relational* database, so an "Object *Relational* Mapper" doesn't seem like the right term here...

Comment: There Changed from ORM to ODM thanks for catching that

Comment: I think technically Redis is not a document database either; rather it is a key-value store ;)

Comment: Actually, Redis is a Database.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/database?s=t Regardless of what the developers claim it isn't to get out of delivering features. It is, by definition a database.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is pretty simple to work with directly or to wrap your own objects around, but you could use an OHM (Object Hash Mapper) like [Nohm](http://maritz.github.com/nohm/):

- source: https://github.com/maritz/nohm
- documentation: http://maritz.github.com/nohm/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [redblade](https://github.com/newghost/redblade)

Just one file. Help you create and remove index fields automatically.